# OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback not triggering in PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

```
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceFragment implements OnPreferenceClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
   != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
      new String[]{ android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
      Constant.WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION);

}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grants) { }
```

I'm trying to get the new permissions. The dialog shows up requesting the permission when it should, but onRequestPermissionResult it's never called, be it rejection or acceptance.

Any idea? The examples are all using Activity and not a Fragment, so that might be the problem. Also, I'm not sure which Compat I should be using (v4 vs v13). Min SDK is 14.

Answer (score 2):

full code for you:

```
public interface PermissionResultListener {
        public void onPermissionResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults);
    }



  public class Preferences extends PreferenceFragment implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener,
        PermissionResultListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void requestPermission() {

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null && activity instanceof MainActivity) {
            MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
            mainActivity.requestPermissionStorage();
            mainActivity.setPermissionResultListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        // request permission result here
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PermissionResultListener mPermissionResultListener;

    public void setPermissionResultListener(PermissionResultListener mPermissionResultListener) {
        this.mPermissionResultListener = mPermissionResultListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            Preferences preferences = new Preferences();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            preferences.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, preferences).commit();
        }

    }

    public void requestPermissionStorage() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    Constant.WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (mPermissionResultListener != null) {
            mPermissionResultListener.onPermissionResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Same result. How is any different? The problem is `public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {}` is never called.

Comment: Also, what is `activity.setPermissionResultListener()` and `permissionResultListener.onPermissionResult`?

Comment: @xBlue, public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {}, this method was only called in activity, not in fragment, so you must implement this method in activity, to connect between activity and fragment, you must create interface PermissionResultListener. mean in your activity, you must declare variable permissionResultListener and method public void setPermissionResultListener(PermissionResultListener permissionResultListener)

Comment: what activity? Can you give an example?

Comment: I have edited the answer above. you can review again.

Comment: did u get solution. I m also facing same problem. Pls advice if it is working for u.